# PhoneStateListener is not always notified on cellular network changes

Tags: android, networking, cellular-network

My app listens for cellular network type changes, to that effect I use a [`PhoneStateListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) and listen for [`LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE), handling `onDataConnectionStateChanged`, which gets the network type.
Documentation is a bit sparse but I understand this is called when the type of network is changed, and it mostly seem to work; however if I for instance switch manually to 2G-only mode, causing the phone to switch from HSPA to EDGE, my service doesn't get notified.

Am I missing something, or maybe listening to the wrong event?

As a workaround, I've started listening for signal level changes too, which hides the problem in appearance since those are more frequent and give me a chance to check the network type, but the underlying problem of not being notified on some network changes is still there.